# Нужно вывести дату из БД в input type="date" в формате d-m-Y

Tags: php, html, дата, input

У меня есть таблица в базе данных, где хранится дата в формате Y-m-d в поле типа "date". Есть страница на html, где я могу редактировать данные из таблицы, но дата, находящаяся в таблице, в value у input'а типа "дата" не выводится, и надо заново ее устанавливать.
Вот код на php:

```html
<?php
    $list = mysqli_query($id, "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE IDT = '$IDT'");
    $list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list);
    $date = date('d.m.Y', $list['BDay']); //вот тут и не работает
?>
```

Вот input из формы на html:

```html
<p>Дата рождения : <input type = "date" name = "BDay" value = '<?=$date?>'></p>
```

Не работают также и эти варианты:

1.

```html
$date = date ('d-m-Y', strtotime($list['BDay']));
```

```html
<p>Дата рождения : <input type = "date" name = "BDay" value = '<?=$date?>'></p>
```

2. с тем же html

```html
$date = date ('d.m.Y', $list['BDay']);
```

Как же преобразовать дату из базы данных так, чтобы она выводилась в value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю с чего вы решили, что нужен формат "dd-mm-yyyy", потому что в документации: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date#%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5  написано что там формат "yyyy-mm-dd"

> Помните, что отображаемый формат даты отличается от настоящего
> значения value – отображаемый формат даты будет выбран, базируясь на
> региональных параметрах браузера пользователя, тогда как значение
> value **всегда имеет формат гггг-мм-дд**.

```html
<input id="date" type="date" value="2017-06-01">
```

Answer (score 0):

Алексей спас таких же тупых, как я. Если кому не ясно, вот как это должно выглядеть:

```html
<?php
    $list = mysqli_query($id, "SELECT * FROM `teacher` WHERE `IDT` = '$IDT'");
    $list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list);
    $date = $list['BDay'];
?>
```

И на html:

```html
<p>Дата рождения : <input type = "date" name = "BDay" value = '<?=$date?>'></p>
```